# Compare rows in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to compare rows in the same table of a query.

Here is an example of the table:

```
id    checkin     checkout    
1     01/15/13    01/31/13
1     01/31/13    05/20/13
2     01/15/13    05/20/13
3     01/15/13    01/19/13
3     01/19/13    05/20/13
4     01/15/13    02/22/13
5     01/15/13    03/01/13
```

I compare the checkout date to today's date, if it is before today's date then I want to return the result.  However, similar to id's 1 and 3, they have multiple records.  If one of the records associated with the same id have a record that has a checkout date after today's date then I don't want to return any of their records.  I only want to return a record of each id where every record is before today's date in the checkout field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, analytic functions are the best approach:

```
select id, checkin, checkout
from (select t.*, max(checkout) over (partition by id) as maxco
      from t
     ) t
where maxco <= trunc(sysdate)
```

This assumes that the data is stored as date values and not as strings (otherwise, the max will return the wrong value).

Comment: I'm trying to use this with multiple tables because I am comparing the checkout date in a separate table.  Do I just end finish the first from with: from(....)t1,t2  ?

Comment: @trueinViso . . . I think you should ask another question, about multiple tables.  Include table format, sample data, and the results that you want.  This question is very clearly starts "I need to compare rows in the same table of a query".

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, checking  from
Table 
where checkout < CURRENT_DATE --Postgresql date of today, Oracle should have an equivalent now
and id not in (select id from Table where checkout >= CURRENT_DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you all the results of records that are before in time and that all with the same id are also before in time.

```
SELECT Ta.* 
 FROM TABLE Ta,
      (SELECT MAX(checkout) checkout, ID FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID) Tb
WHERE Ta.ID = Tb.ID 
  AND sysdate >= Ta.checkout -- checks for date in current record
  AND sysdate >= Tb.checkout -- checks for dates in all records
```